# Building application using ZendFramework

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in ZendFramework. I am using windowsXP and xampp.I am tring to build a small application using ZendFramework.But I got the below errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for Users' in E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php:755
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(739): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupDatabaseAdapter()
#1 E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(268): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setup()
#2 E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table.php(77): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\testproject\application\controllers\IndexController.php(7): Zend_Db_Table->__construct()
#4 E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): IndexController->indexAction()
#5 E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#6 E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_ in E:\xampp\php\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php on line 755
```

Can anyone say what is the solution??

Thanks

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

These are the content of application.ini file.

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
       $users = new Users();
       $data = $users->fetchAll($users->select());
       $this->view->data = $data;
   }
}

?>
```

These are the content of IndexController.php file

@RockyFord

Do you mean that application.ini file should like below??

```
    [production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
    phpSettings.display_errors = 0
    includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
    bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
    bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
    appnamespace = "Application"
    resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

    resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql" //PDO is best option, other adapters are available.
    resources.db.params.username = "your_username"
    resources.db.params.password = "your_password"
    resources.db.params.dbname = "your_database_name"
    resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true //this line is optional but recommended.


    [staging : production]

    [testing : production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1

    [development : production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: Can you post your application.ini? (**without** any sensitive information like passwords of course)

Comment: And perhaps, also post the line in the `IndexController` where you instantiate the `Zend_Db_Table` object.

Comment: missing DB configuration for Zend_Db_Table ?

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the location where the app is running? (command line, phpMyAdmin, etc...). Also do you have the pdo extension loaded? Are you sure your mysql credentials are correct?

Comment: sorry it took so long, but yes that is the correct file. Just make you have setup a database in mysql before you try to connect to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are using mysql add these lines to your application.ini in the production section.

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql" //PDO is best option, other adapters are available.
resources.db.params.username = "your_username"
resources.db.params.password = "your_password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "your_database_name"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true //this line is optional but recommended.
```

Comment: @Michael Irey,
I am new in ZendFramework. I could not understand your words.